# Where do I set the maximum query string length?

Tags: iis, iis-10

From an HTTP request with a loooong query string - 2847 in this case -, I got back error 404.15 with the following message:

> Überprüfen Sie die Einstellung "configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits@maxQueryString" in der Datei "applicationhost.config" oder "web.config".

In English:

> Check the "configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits@maxQueryString" setting in the "applicationhost.config" or "web.config" file.

I did this, by following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/) and changing the maximum query string length from 2048 to 4096 characters.

Evidently, the above change *has* had an effect, as the original error message is gone.

Instead, I am now getting *another* error, *still* related to the maximum query string length. This time, it comes with HTTP code 400 and says:

> Die Länge der Abfragezeichenfolge für die Anforderung überschreitet den konfigurierten maxQueryStringLength-Wert.

In English:

> The query string length of the request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value.

Now, I have scanned all `*.config` files on my entire disks for any occurrences of the substring `maxQueryString`. There is only one such occurrence in total, and it is the `Web.config` file for my IIS default website, which says

```
<requestLimits maxQueryString="4096" />
```

**Hence, something else must be influencing the maximum query length - where else can this setting me configured?**

Comment: Check the event log on the server, it may shed more light.  You have to identify which web.config needs to be updated -- and there likely WON'T be a maxQueryStringLength there, and it will need to be created.  The entry in the web.config should look something like:  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" maxUrlLength="2048" maxQueryStringLength="10240" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, make sure you enabled the anonymous authentication in iis:

set below code in web.config file:

```
<system.web>

   <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="10999" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" />
                                ……
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxUrl="10999" maxQueryString="2097151" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Note: set value a little bit higher than your requirement. above mentioned is just an example.
set this value in the root folder config file. and restart iis after doing changes.

Comment: Setting both values as described here appears to solve the problem, thank you (will accept i a moment) :) I'm not sure why anonymous authentication is relevant here, though.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper if your issue is resolved then I request you mark the suggestion as an answer it will help other people who face similar issue.

Comment: I will, see "will accept i a moment" in my previous comment - as soon as my co-worker has confirmed that this works on their system, as well.